# How to get Original User after Impersonating another user?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Switch user filter given by spring for Impersonating an user.

How can I get the Original user Who is Impersonating in the SwitchUserFilter.

Steps I am doing:

Ex.

```
1. Log in with User1 
2. Impersonting to the User2. (user1 impersonate User2)
3. In Filter I am getting **authentication.getName()** as **User2**
4. While switching back to Original I am getiing **authentication.getName()** as **Null**
```

Now My Need is I want to get the original user (**User1**) in the filter at the time of swtichback.

Can it be possible.

Please suggest.
Let me know anyone needs any more inputs. please comment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share some sample code on how you were able to get user2 in the filter as mentioned in step#3? When I checked the Principal from the targetUrl set in filter.setTargetUrl(), I still get user1.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can access the original User :

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();

for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
    if (SwitchUserFilter.ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMINISTRATOR.equals(grantedAuthority.getAuthority())) {
        System.out.println(((SwitchUserGrantedAuthority) grantedAuthority).getSource().getPrincipal());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add this custom method in UserJwTController in jhipster generated application

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate-externalnodes")
    public ResponseEntity<JWTToken> authenticateExternalnodes(@Valid @RequestBody LoginVM loginVM) {
        // Get Roles for user via username
        Set<Authority> authorities = userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(loginVM.getUsername()).get()
                .getAuthorities();
        // Create Granted Authority Rules
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Authority authority : authorities) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()));
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                loginVM.getUsername(), "", grantedAuthorities);
        Authentication authentication = authenticationToken;
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        boolean rememberMe = (loginVM.isRememberMe() == null) ? false : loginVM.isRememberMe();
        String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, rememberMe);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(JWTFilter.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + jwt);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new JWTToken(jwt), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```